# "Git: Failed to execute git" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-commit

I'm following a tutorial to create a remote Git repository, clone it locally, add a README.md file and then save and commit locally then push remotely.

I have followed word for word a few times but when I get to "commit staged changes" every time it says:

> Git: Failed to execute git

This is all using Visual Studio Code.

I'm not sure where to go from here and have no idea how to fix this.

This is just after I've pressed "commit":

[image: Just after I've pressed commit]

Comment: It sounds like either a) you never did the `git init` step to create a new local repository, or b) you did do `git init`, but you are trying to execute a Git command from outside the Git project folder.  Please check for both of these possibilities.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought I did the git init as I have no idea what it is haha how would I do that? Sorry extremely new to this

Comment: I take back what I said, you should have already cloned a repo from GitHub.  After you typed `git clone <URL>`, did it work?  What did `git status` tell you from the same location?

Comment: Yeah I cloned it, and it worked, it has come up and created a folder in my computer. It let me add the file and then it lets me stage it but from there just won't commit. The file is in the folder on my computer aswell and i open it in notebook and it says what i put in it. But because it failed to commit it wont let me push to github as well.

Comment: **Edit** your question and show us the exact Git commands you used.  It sounds now like the problem was with not committing, and then the push failed.

Comment: Yeah I think thats the problem, I just edited to attach a photo at the end if that helps, and that is the git log it opens when i press that button.

Comment: Exactly what I did was Ctrl, Shift, P and typed git: clone, then entered the URL from github. From there I went to the explorer project and clicked create new file. I then named it README.md and wrote 'Hello world, I'm new to git' (as the tutorial told me to write). Saved the file, then went into source control:git and my file was in changes so I pressed stage changes, from there pressed commit then that'ts where the photo is up to.

Comment: Did you bother to pay attention to the feedback Git gave you?  You need to configure your Git username and email, otherwise it generally won't get you commit.  So, do those steps.  I can't give a formal answer, because the odds of something else also being wrong are very high.

Comment: Yeah I read it but didnt know how to do that and the tutorial didnt mention anything about it. I tried openning git but didnt give much help. How do i configure my git username? and do i make up anything or needs to line up with something? and any email? I do appreciate your help

Comment: Um...when you got that error message you certainly could have done what Git said, and added your username and email.  Not sure where the confusion is here.

Comment: I don't know where to add my username and email? I dont know what my username is? is this something I should have already set up? As i've said this is my first time and I have just followed the online course word for word. Do i open Git and do it? Or do it from visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize a Git repo for your project. To do this:

Inside of your Visual Studio Code Project, press <kbd>Ctrl + `</kbd>.

A terminal window will show up!

Enter: `git init`