# "Git: Failed to execute" when trying to commit changes

Tags: git, github

When I try to commit changes via Visual Studio I've got this message:

> Git: Failed to execute

When I push my project the console log `Everything up-to-date`.

When I type `git status` I have the following log:

```
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'master/main'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   backend (modified content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Moreover on Github.com I can't acceed to some folders there is an arrow to the right (I can post a picture or a link to my repo if asked).

Everything was working fine until yesterday and I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: You're reporting a problem when _committing_, another one related to _pushing_, and a third problem related to folder access on Github. It will be better to not mix these issues in a single question.

Answer (score -2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57166275/17326134

Try this, or use git status to display if you made some changes that needed to be pushed. If so, please add changes then commit and fix some conflicts. then you can git pull or fetch --all.

Also, try git fetch --all first then add and commit changes.

Comment: Since they can type `git status` and get a response, not having initialized a Git repository doesn't seem to be the problem.